# How do I set web icon for my android app?

Tags: android

In android studio I have already set the icon for mdpi, hdpi, etc.... , but I don't know where to put the web icon in android studio. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "web icon"?

Comment: You mean to say app icon?

Comment: Apps aren't web targets.  If you mean a graphic for an app market, you will set it in the console of that when you upload.  If you mean something for a web site promoting your app, then on your web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hi-Res Web Icon is used for your store listing on Google Play only.  I have a folder in the root of my project called PlayStoreAssets in which I keep my screenshots and my other assets, however, that is completely unnecessary.